# Alexa not invoking the Intent

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I was trying to make an alexa skill, which is based on the fact skill of the alexa's blueprint. I've made a custom Intent named "myIntent", which has a variable "{myName}" or slot type "myNameSlot". I've added multiple values like "Dhruv,User,My User" (all are separate values).

So, I tried to launch my Alexa skill in Test via the simulator. It is launching all the in-built intents just fine. However, when I try to launch my custom Intent, it doesn't launch.I wrote the same utterances, however, it is not being invoked.

Here's my Lambda Function's code : https://pastebin.com/7CrdMffW

```
/* eslint-disable  func-names */
/* eslint quote-props: ["error", "consistent"]*/
/**
 * This sample demonstrates a simple skill built with the Amazon Alexa Skills
 * nodejs skill development kit.
 * This sample supports multiple lauguages. (en-US, en-GB, de-DE).
 * The Intent Schema, Custom Slots and Sample Utterances for this skill, as well
 * as testing instructions are located at https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-fact
 **/

'use strict';
const Alexa = require('alexa-sdk');

//=========================================================================================================================================
//TODO: The items below this comment need your attention.
//=========================================================================================================================================

//Replace with your app ID (OPTIONAL).  You can find this value at the top of your skill's page on http://developer.amazon.com.
//Make sure to enclose your value in quotes, like this: const APP_ID = 'amzn1.ask.skill.bb4045e6-b3e8-4133-b650-72923c5980f1';
const APP_ID = undefined;

const SKILL_NAME = 'Space Facts';
const GET_FACT_MESSAGE = "Here's your fact: ";
const HELP_MESSAGE = 'You can say tell me a space fact, or, you can say exit... What can I help you with?';
const HELP_REPROMPT = 'What can I help you with?';
const STOP_MESSAGE = 'Goodbye!';

//=========================================================================================================================================
//TODO: Replace this data with your own.  You can find translations of this data at http://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-node-js-fact/data
//=========================================================================================================================================
const data = [
    'A year on Mercury is just 88 days long.',
    'Despite being farther from the Sun, Venus experiences higher temperatures than Mercury.',
    'Venus rotates counter-clockwise, possibly because of a collision in the past with an asteroid.',
    'On Mars, the Sun appears about half the size as it does on Earth.',
    'Earth is the only planet not named after a god.',
    'Jupiter has the shortest day of all the planets.',
    'The Milky Way galaxy will collide with the Andromeda Galaxy in about 5 billion years.',
    'The Sun contains 99.86% of the mass in the Solar System.',
    'The Sun is an almost perfect sphere.',
    'A total solar eclipse can happen once every 1 to 2 years. This makes them a rare event.',
    'Saturn radiates two and a half times more energy into space than it receives from the sun.',
    'The temperature inside the Sun can reach 15 million degrees Celsius.',
    'The Moon is moving approximately 3.8 cm away from our planet every year.',
];

//=========================================================================================================================================
//Editing anything below this line might break your skill.
//=========================================================================================================================================

const handlers = {
    'LaunchRequest': function () {
        // this.emit('myIntent');
        this.emit(':tell', '2 Hello, what would you like to do?');
    },
    'myIntent': function () {
        const factArr = data;
        const factIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * factArr.length);
        const randomFact = factArr[factIndex];
        const speechOutput = GET_FACT_MESSAGE + randomFact;

        this.response.cardRenderer(SKILL_NAME, randomFact);
        this.response.speak('Halo ' + speechOutput);
        this.emit(':responseReady');
    },
    'AMAZON.HelpIntent': function () {
        const speechOutput = HELP_MESSAGE;
        const reprompt = HELP_REPROMPT;

        this.response.speak(speechOutput).listen(reprompt);
        this.emit(':responseReady');
    },
    'AMAZON.CancelIntent': function () {
        this.response.speak(STOP_MESSAGE);
        this.emit(':responseReady');
    },
    'AMAZON.StopIntent': function () {
        this.response.speak(STOP_MESSAGE);
        this.emit(':responseReady');
    },
};

exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
    const alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context, callback);
    alexa.APP_ID = APP_ID;
    alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
    alexa.execute();
};
```

I'm not sure what's happening here.

**EDIT:** This is the information about my Intent and custom slot :

**Intent Name :** `myIntent`.

**Utterances :**

1.) tell me about {data_of_intent}

2.) what is the synopsys of {data_of_intent}

**Intent Slots (1) :** `data_of_intent` of type `my_custom_type`.

**Custom Slot Type Values :**

1.)  one piece

2.) Flower Dream

3.) Kanai kun

4.) Has the rain stopped?

Comment: You said "I wrote the same utterances...", What exactly are the utterances you wrote for `myIntent`?

Comment: I've edited my question and added more information about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I double checked the JSON I was receiving on the first hit.The issue was that `shouldEndSession` was set to true and that's because, in NodeJS, `shouldEndSession` is set to true in `:tell` and cannot be overridden.

I was using :

`this.emit(':tell', '2 Hello, what would you like to do?');`.

I changed it to :

`this.emit(':ask', '2 Hello, what would you like to do?');`

and it worked.

There's a Github thread for the same : https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/issues/64